# Is the Lie bracket of two vector fields well defined?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, gradient-flows

I want to understand what exactly means to ask the question if the Lie bracket $[X,Y]$ of two vector fields $X,Y\in \mathcal{XM}$, where $\mathcal{M}$ is a differentiable manifold, is **well defined**.

- What does it mean conceptually that the Lie bracket is well defined?
- How could I prove that indeed it is well defined?
- Can I do it use it a specific basis, say, $e_x = \partial/\partial x$ and $e_y = \partial / \partial y$?

Comment: It depends on what your attempt at a definition is. There is a definition in terms of flows which has no well-definedness issues. The definition that might have well-definedness issues is a definition using local coordinates; then you need to show that the Lie bracket doesn't depend on a choice of coordinates.

Comment: Hi, I know the definition in terms of flows. I am not comfortable though with the "well definiteness" of it. I understand what you mean with the local coordinates. You mean that Lie bracket must be a global object. How then do we find all such possible obstacles in order the Lie bracket to be well defined? What does the flow definition make it well defined?

Answer (score 4):

The standard definition of the Lie bracket is: For a differentiable function $f$ on $M$ and two vector fields $X, Y$ on $M$,
$$
[X,Y](f)= XY(f) - YX(f). 
$$
You need to check that this defines a [derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(differential_algebra)) on the space of functions on $M$. Doing so is a very nice exercise in the definitions (the more interesting part is verifying the Leibnitz rule).

Answer (score -1):

If $X$ and $Y$ are two vector fields, $[X,Y]=DY(X)-DX(Y)$. Here $DX$ is the differential of $X$.

You can see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_bracket_of_vector_fields

Comment: This is perhaps a strange answer (I'm not the downvoter, incidentally) in the following sense: This formula holds for *torsion-free* connections $D$, but (1) since one must choose a connection $D$, one must verify that the definition is independent of choice of $D$, and (2) this is circular insofar as the equation in the definition is actually how torsion-freeness of a connection is usually defined.